# Can someone explain to me why $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\emptyset)) = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Would someone explain the reasoning of the answer of

> $$\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\emptyset)) = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$

I am having trouble understanding this

Comment: $\mathscr{P}(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\},\\\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}.$

Comment: Powersets are never empty.

Comment: $2^0 =1, 2^{(2^0)} = 2$, in cardinals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there's no such thing as an empty powerset.  The smallest powerset is the powerset of the empty set, which is a singleton with one element, namely $\emptyset$.  So $P(\emptyset)$ is a singleton, $\{\emptyset\}$.  The powerset of a singleton contains the singleton set and the emptyset, thus $P(P(\emptyset))=P(\{\emptyset\})=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ for the same reason $P(\{1\})=\{\emptyset,\{1\}\}$.